How to cancel the coroutine inside runBlocking?
I have code which scans rows from a database and produces those rows in batches as a producer channel. I want to concurrently process the batches as new ones come in. I then want to watch for errors, and if any occur, cancel both the producer channel and the data processor. Here is my sample code:
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Starting runBlocking.")
    try {
        runBlocking {
            // produceData is my producer channel
            val data = produceData()
            var count = 0
            data.consumeEach { batch ->
                yield()
                count++
                if (count >= 10) {
                    println("Reached 10th batch, cancelling...")
                    // cancel here
                    cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        println("Exception encountered.")
        println(e.stackTraceToString())
    }
    
    println("After runBlocking.")
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun CoroutineScope.produceData(): ReceiveChannel<List<Data>> {
    return produce {
        db.connection.use { conn ->
            conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).use { stmt ->
                stmt.fetchSize = Int.MIN_VALUE

                val sql = // omitted working SQL

                stmt.executeQuery(sql).use { rs ->
                    val batch = mutableListOf<Data>()
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        // Handle result set here
                        val data = Data(...) // omitted model mapper
                        batch.add(data)
                        if (batch.size >= 100) {
                            send(batch)
                            batch.clear()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The current behavior is that I get the following output:
Starting runBlocking.
Reached 10th batch, cancelling...

After that, it just hangs. I know the database code is working. I want to see "After runBlocking" to show that I'm able to exit the runBlocking correctly.
What am I doing wrong here? I've tried saving the coroutineContext from runBlocking and cancelling that, cancelling just it's children, etc. I've tried adding yield() calls to both the producer and the consumer. How can I, from within the runBlocking { ... } block, cancel the producer channel and consumer such that the runBlocking ends?

This is not easily reproducible without your database. Does the problem still persist when you replace the produce's lambda with repeat(100) { delay(500); send(listOf(Data(it))) }? Assuming Data to be data class Data(val id: Int).

There are other problems with your code, but they probably are unrelated to the behavior you observe. First, if the db is blocking, then please be aware we shouldn't us blocking code in coroutines. As a matter of fact, it will ignore cancellations while performing a blocking I/O, however, it doesn't seem this is the case here. Second, you send a list through the channel, then you mutate it. Maybe (but only maybe) it will work with runBlocking due to limited parallelism, but this is generally a risky thing to do.

@Leviathan changing the code as you describe does achieve the behavior I'm looking for, so clearly it's something to do with producing data from a database call like this.

@broot For your second point, yeah that is an issue I was aware of and had fixed in my production code (this is a contrived example to figure out coroutines). I changed it to be var batch = mutableListOf<Data>() and set that variable to a new list every send(), but problem is still there. For your first point, I'm not sure how to answer, I guess it is? I'm just using JDBC behaviors which do not understand coroutines natively. Can I detect if the outer context has been cancelled and close my database connection manually somehow?

Update, I think I have isolated the problem to being with the database code. Basically, what I have does not actually cancel the long-running query. I'm using MySQL in case anyone is interested. I'm gonna close this issue as it does not apply to Kotlin coroutines, but after searching around, it seems overly difficult, if not impossible, to actually cancel a query in MySQL using JDBC function calls, but that is for another post.

Yes, you won't be able to cancel a long-running JDBC query. I would definitely try stmt.cancel() when detected a cancellation. For this you need at least 2 threads as one of them is blocked in I/O.
